# Can I consider my LAN server as forward proxy?

Tags: proxy

In a LAN network, my machine is connected to the LAN server and my machine is connected to internet through LAN server. So, can I consider the LAN server as forward proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not typically.

If all traffic passes through the 'LAN server', you can consider the LAN server a gateway and a NAT-router.

If only HTTP/HTTPS/FTP traffic passes through the LAN server you might indeed be using an application proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up `squid`, for example, on your server and use it to get `http` content from the internet, then yes, the squid is a `forwarding proxy` service. If your server is running some `DNS` server to forward your queries to upstream DNS server (even such a small as dnsmasq), then yes, this DNS server is a `forwarding proxy` service.